# How do I make predictions on the MNIST dataset with reshaping?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

```
I'm working on a simple example of a ANN using the MNIST dataset. I think I understand the basic breakdown of the model, including reshaping the data, but I'm having trouble with the prediction aspect. 

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=["accuracy"])

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype("float32") / 255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype("float32") / 255

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
model.predict(test_images)

img = test_images[4].reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(img)

model.predict(test_images[4])
```

When I predict on "img,"  I get the following error: " ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape (None, 1)." However, I reshaped "IMG," so I'm not sure how to fix the error to test the model's prediction. I also tried model.predict(img). Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

After doing predictions for all the images, you can check the prediction probability of a specific image using prediction indexing.

```
predictions = model.predict(test_images)
predictions[4]
```

Output:

```
array([2.23070249e-01, 1.56941269e-07, 7.61738047e-03, 1.05438616e-04,
       6.13741344e-04, 1.86085714e-07, 7.68570304e-01, 1.20229133e-08,
       2.23877323e-05, 1.23962650e-07], dtype=float32)
```

Hence, you can remove this code `model.predict(test_images[4])` and please check the below code to get the predicted label for the given image:

```
img = test_images[4].reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(img)

#model.predict(test_images[4])
pred_img = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[4])]
pred_img
```

Output:

[image]

Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification#make_predictions) link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code below:

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype("float32") / 255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype("float32") / 255
```

Use this code:
**Your layers arent getting correct input shape**

```
X_train, X_test = X_train / 255, X_test /255
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, -1)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, -1)

X_train.shape    // Shape should be (60000,28,28,1)

//Before using labels do this
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, K)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, K)
```